# readline() and read() behavior in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have python script as written below -

```
steps = open("Steps.txt", mode='r')
firstLine = steps.readline()
print(firstLine)
print('__________'*10)
print(steps.read())
```

I was expecting this to print first line and then complete file content as given below -

```
This is the First Line.
_____________________________________________________________________________
This is the First Line.
This is the Second Line.
This is the Third Line.
```

But the actual output is -

```
This is the First Line.
_____________________________________________________________________________
This is the Second Line.
This is the Third Line.
```

Can anyone please explain the filereader behavior in python3.4.

Comment: file content is -
This is the First Line.
This is the Second Line.
This is the Third Line.                                                                         Consider all three sentences in a different line

Comment: File objects in python are [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)